# How to evict/remove a bean from a Spring Custom Scope?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How does one remove a bean in a custom scope in Spring?

I was reading the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.20.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-custom) and I couldn't find/understand how it's supposed to be done. For instance, how am I suppose to evict a bean from a scope after a certain condition is reached? Should I autowire an instance of my custom scope and invoke `Object remove(String name)` on it?